# guvcview records audio but only first frame of video

Tags: ubuntu, video, lubuntu

`guvcview` used to work okay, but then there was an update and it stopped working. It records audio okay but only the first frame of video shows.

I've tried different rendering methods, no difference except `-r 2` "software" doesn't show the first image.

When I run `guvcview --verbosity=2` there is one line that pops up an error.

```
WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
```

But that might be a red herring. Other info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ uname -m
i686

$ guvcview --version
Guvcview version 2.0.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/guvcview/+bug/1558060

There is a [patched build available](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/guvcview/+bug/1558060/comments/16), for 16.04, so you may give it a try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pj-assis/ubuntu/testing
apt-get update
apt-get install guvcview
```